# read json in Python

Tags: python, json

I can't believe it's not working! Here is my sample.json file:

```
{
  "SupportedTests": [
    "example1",
    "example2",
    "example3"
  ],
  "ExecutableFilePath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe"
}
```

and the python code for reading this file:

```
# Opening JSON file
with open('sample.json') as jsonfile:
    jsonfile.seek(0)
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
```

Here is the error messsage:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any idea why this is not working? It's driving me nuts!
Thanks

Comment: In your code snippet you didn't include the opening `{` in the JSON, is it there in the file ?

Comment: It was there actually, due to bad formatting it was gone :p

Comment: @arhr yes I forgot to put it here. still not working.

Comment: There is a trailing comma in your json

Comment: use ```from glob import glob``` and ```print(glob('*.json'))``` to check the ```sample.json``` is actually there

Comment: @NidalBarada If the file wasn't there, the `open()` call would have thrown an exception

Comment: I'm guessing that you have two files named `sample.json`.  The one given in the question must be in a different directory, and the one actually being opened by the program is empty.

Answer (score 3):

**Edited to reflect latest question change**

Your code is valid and should open and parse the file fine. Note that you don't need `jsonfile.seek(0)`

The error indicates that the file you've opened is empty - are you sure the path to the file with the JSON is correct?

---

**Original answer**

Your json has a comma at the end of this line `"ExecutableFilePath": "C:\\Program Files\\Python37\\python.exe",`. This is invalid json and won't be parsed.

Because your have this comma, the parser is expecting another key in the json object - hence a string is expected.

Ensure that your JSON is valid with this tool: [www.jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com)

Comment: @D Hudson that was a typo, I fixed it and validate the json file. Same issue exists.

Comment: This wouldn't cause the error `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`, would it?

Comment: Thanks, no it wouldn't - good point! Answer updated